# My select dont receive the scroll webkit (styled components)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

Im conding whit react and styled components, just trying to make a simple page to teste a API, but i cant stylize the scroll bar.

That is the react HTML part.

```
return(
<Grid>
        <Titulo> Escolha seu estado </Titulo>
        <Formulario 
            value={estado}
            onChange={event => setEstado(event.target.value)}
        >
            <option value="" hidden >Selecione o seu estado</option>
            {options.map(option => {
                return (
                    <option value={option.id}>{option.nome}</option>
                )
            })}
        </Formulario>  

        <Titulo> Escolha sua cidade </Titulo>
        <Formulario 
            className=" "
            value={estado}
            onChange={event => setEstado(event.target.value)}
        >
            <option value="" hidden >Selecione sua cidade</option>
            {options.map(option => {
                return (
                    <option value={option.id}>{option.nome}</option>
                )
            })}
        </Formulario>  
   

</Grid>
)
```

And that my styled components part

```
 import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Grid = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: flex-start; 
    option{
        background-color: var(--box);
        
    }
`;

export const Titulo = styled.div`
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 28px;
color: var(--texto);
margin: 15px 0 5px 0;

`;

export const Formulario = styled.select`
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 303px;
    height: 33px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: var(--box);
    color: var(--pesquisa);
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    :hover{
        color: var(--pesquisaClick);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        background-color: red;
    }
    
`;
```

(i put BG-color red just to text, i already tested with none)

My site:
[image]

The problem:

[image]

Im already tried to put the webkit in div ( Grid is the name , just a name, im really using flex, i will change)

Answer (score 3):

Try to define something like this in a css that is applied to the entire app:

```
$dark-blue: #172449;
$dark-blue-o-5: mix($dark-blue, #fff, 5%);
$dark-blue-o-10: mix($dark-blue, #fff, 10%);
$dark-blue-o-20: mix($dark-blue, #fff, 20%);
        
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: $dark-blue-o-5;
    border: 1px solid $dark-blue-o-20;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: .5s;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: $dark-blue-o-10;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background: $dark-blue-o-10;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid $dark-blue-o-20;
    border-radius: 0;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
    background: #ffffff;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, idk if i understand right. Can u tell me if i need to put this in "Formulario = styled.select`" or i need to create a new css style, put this and import to the index.js(react index)

Comment: Ok, i put this in a new css file and import to main react file.
Now the page scroll bar is blue, and the select no

Comment: @LucasRM Probably the scrollbar of a select cannot be customized, unfortunately customization of inputs is complicated. Sometimes to change the style of some inputs it is necessary to use the following css attribute: `appearance: none`. This will force the browser to ignore default input styles.

Comment: The `*` selector will apply style to anything rendered in browser if it won't work with this so probably it isn't possible to style a select dropdown scroll bar. An alternative is to create a custom select. Something like that: https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz